# I have three controllers extended from Getx I would like to build view with them in one page but I only allowed to use one controller

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

`I tried to use If statement and pass the controller in every statement, But I only can get items from one controller. I also tried to make in column with separated builder, I can now see all my products, but everyone separated in like container or sth, What I am thinking at is to make method to hold all three controllers, But the point is every controller has its own data.
Any help

```
      GetBuilder<ProductController>(
          builder: (productController)=>
              GetBuilder<PromotionController>(
              builder: (promotionController)=>
                  GetBuilder<CoffeeController>
                (builder: (coffeeController) =>

                      Expanded(
                        child:
                        Obx((){
                          if(promotionController.favList.isNotEmpty){
                            return ListView.separated(
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return buildFavItems(
                                    image: promotionController.favList[index].image,
                                    price: promotionController.favList[index].price,
                                    title: promotionController.favList[index].title,
                                    productId: promotionController.favList[index].id,
                                  );
                                },
                                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return const Divider(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    thickness: 1,
                                  );
                                },
                                itemCount: promotionController.favList.length);
```

Comment: final controller = Get.put(ProductController());
  final promotionController = Get.put(PromotionController());
  final coffeeController = Get.put(CoffeeController());

Comment: i would like to pass the data from these three controller in one page